# Как поместить ID класса в скобки в asp.net

Tags: asp.net, классы

Как сделать, чтобы класс был в скобках:

`tcellkey.ID="keylic" + i.ToString();`  - воводиться как **keylic1**, **keylic2** и т.д.

Нужно чтоб было **keylic(1)**, **keylic(2)** и т.д.

Comment: `tcellkey.ID = $"keylic({i})";` покрасивее будет

Comment: @AGS17 Ну да. Так куда приятнее=)

Answer (score 3):

Самый простой и очевидный для вас вариант -- это выполнить конкатенацию строк:

```
tcellkey.ID="keylic(" + i.ToString() + ")";
```

, при этом обратите внимание, что студия вам предложит убрать излишний .ToString() с сообщением Redundant object.ToString() call for value type -- вы можете написать просто:

```
tcellkey.ID="keylic(" + i + ")";
```

Так нагляднее и чище.

Однако есть ещё более хорошие варианты.

До выхода [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) 6.0 использовали `String.Format`:

```
tcellkey.ID=String.Format("keylic({0})", i);
```

С выходом [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) 6.0 вы можете использовать интерполяцию строк:

```
tcellkey.ID = $"keylic({i})";
```

Какой вариант выбрать?

Наилучший вариант -- последний, если вы можете использовать c# 6, после него лучше использовать `String.Format`.

В двух словах эта [тема на хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/249555/).

Comment: Для более ранней версии фреймворка — `tcellkey.ID=String.Format("keylic({0})", i);`

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk добавил ваш вариант. Сделал сообщение общим. Если есть у кого ещё предложения - добавляйте.

Comment: Переписал ответ, уточнив версию фреймворка. Вписал ключевое слово: "интерполяция строк", хоть погуглить можно будет желающим.

Comment: @AK Спасибо! Теперь ответ выглядит действительно хорошо.